# Making equations separated

Tags: tables, math-mode, horizontal-alignment, formatting

I've been new to LaTeX and was tasked to rewrite certain pages of our tutor handbooks for our math classes. I've figured how to do most things but I get stuck when trying to replicate something like this:[image]

where all the equations are separated into like an invisible table. How would I go about writing something like this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Please provide the code of what you have so far.

Comment: Don't reproduce it exactly: there are some LaTeX errors in the image.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use of the `align` defined in the `amsmath` package. As starting point:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
a & = b     &   c & = d     &   e &= f 
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**
Since meanwhile @Sebastiano rewrite first your first two equations, I (shameless) take his code of them to show, how can looks my original answer after inserting real equations in it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%---------------- Show page layout. Don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dx} \sin x & =\cos x 
    & \frac{d}{dx} \sec x & =\sec x \tan x 
        & \frac{d}{dx} \tan^{-1} x  & = \frac{1}{1+x^2} \\
\frac{d}{dx} \cos x & =-\sin x 
    & \frac{d}{dx} \cot x & =-\csc x  
        & \frac{d}{dx} \csc^{-1} x  & =- \frac{1}{x\sqrt{x^2-1}}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines shows part of page layout)

Comment: Ahahahaahh for your edit.....

Answer (score 2):

I have used in this MWE, for example, the `flalign` enviroment. If you not want enumerate one equation you can put `\nonumber`. If you not want enumerate all the equations you can use `flalign` instead of `flalign*` (see the comment of @Zarko).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{flalign}
\frac{d}{dx} \sin x & =\cos x & \frac{d}{dx} \sec x & =\sec x \tan x & \frac{d}{dx} \tan^{-1} x  & = \frac{1}{1+x^2}\nonumber\\
\frac{d}{dx} \cos x & =-\sin x & \frac{d}{dx} \cot x & =-\csc x  & \frac{d}{dx} \csc^{-1} x  & =- \frac{1}{x\sqrt{x^2-1}}
\end{flalign}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to have the same text/math-font I suggest to use `Cambria Math` with the engine `XeTeX` or `XeLaTeX`, that it is used also in a any document-**Word**.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Cambria}
\setmathfont{Cambria Math}
\begin{document}
Trigonometric Functions: derivates
\begin{flalign*}
\frac{d}{dx} \sin x & =\cos x & \frac{d}{dx} \sec x & =\sec x \tan x & \frac{d}{dx} \tan^{-1} x  & = \frac{1}{1+x^2}\\
\frac{d}{dx} \cos x & =-\sin x & \frac{d}{dx} \cot x & =-\csc x  & \frac{d}{dx} \csc^{-1} x  & =- \frac{1}{x\sqrt{x^2-1}}
\end{flalign*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Better exploited available space! +1. BTW, if OP doesn't like to number equations, (s)he can use `flalign*` ;-)

Comment: @Zarko Very very nice you are Zarko. Thank you very much. Now I improved my strict comment.

Answer (score 2):

The original document left aligned the equations (as opposed to aligning the =).  Also, every column was the same width.  To achieve this effect I used a tabular with a new column type.

MWE borrowed from Sebatiano.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array,collcell}
\usepackage{showframe}% check margins

\newlength{\mycolwidth}
\setlength{\mycolwidth}{\dimexpr \textwidth/3 - 2\tabcolsep}
\newcommand{\mycolumn}[1]{\hbox to \mycolwidth{$\displaystyle #1$\hfill}}
\newcolumntype{D}{>{\collectcell\mycolumn}l<{\endcollectcell}}

\begin{document}
\def\arraystretch{2.2}% increase spacing
\noindent\begin{tabular}{@{}DDD@{}}
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\underline{Trigonometric Functions: derivates}}\\
\frac{d}{dx} \sin x =\cos x & \frac{d}{dx} \sec x =\sec x \tan x & \frac{d}{dx} \tan^{-1} x  = \frac{1}{1+x^2}\\
\frac{d}{dx} \cos x =-\sin x & \frac{d}{dx} \cot x =-\csc x  & \frac{d}{dx} \csc^{-1} x  =- \frac{1}{x\sqrt{x^2-1}}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very kind John. You can take all :-)...(please you write taken and not stolen) :-)

Comment: @Sebastiano - But "stolen" is funnier.

Comment: I understood a bit the English language...:-) "stolen" is rubare in Italian language :-) and I not like it.

Comment: @Sebastiano - I admit that under Noble Values,, stealing is an example of exerting prowess, showing that the thief is superior to the victim.  (See http://www.elfsoft2000.com/politics/class.htm)  That was not my intention.

Comment: Don't worry absolutely. I didn't think anything of it at all and you don't have to apologize. My best regards.